# Matching parenthesis in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to find if a string of parenthesis matches using php.
So I wrote this.

```
<?php  

function Parenthesis($string) {
$ok = preg_match('~(\((?1)*+\)|\[(?1)*+]|{(?1)*+})*\z~A', $string);
if ($ok==1) {
    return "true"; 
} else {
    return "false";
}
}

$entree = "{([]){}()}";
$sortie = Parenthesis($entree);
echo "Réponse : ".$sortie;
```

And it gives `true`.

But when I pass `$entree = "{C{}[{[a]}RqhL]{y2}}";` it gives false, meanwhile I need true.
How can I modify the code.

Comment: `{C{}[{[a]}RqhL]{y2}}` doesn't have any parenthesis. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you can use `\A[^][(){}]*+((?:(\[)|(\()|{)(?:(?!\2).|(?1))*(?(2)]|(?(3)\)|}))[^][(){}]*+)++\z`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8RReM2/1).

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i'm trying to write a script which output is expected to be true if the brackets (), square brackets [] and braces {} are correctly paired in the given line, otherwise false.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help , you demo works perfectly , but once i replace my regular expression with yours , it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made a mistake. There `\2` groups is not what it should be. Actually, the pattern is already too complex and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured something out.

```
function isParenthesis(string $expression){
        $patterns = array('{','}','(',')','[',']');
        $occ = array(0,0,0,0,0,0);

        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($expression); $i++){
            for($j = 0; $j < count($patterns); $j++){
                if($expression[$i] == $patterns[$j]){
                    $occ[$j]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for ($i=0; $i < count($occ); $i+=2) { 
            if($occ[$i] != $occ[$i+1]){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    $str = "{[{iHTSc}]}p(R)m(){q({})";
    echo "l'expression ".$str." est correcte ? : ".isParenthesis($str);
```

And it works greatly ! Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: This code doesn't work correctly. Try it with `"{(})"` which does not have balanced parentheses; it will return true.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably more easily (and robustly) done by parsing the string a character at a time and maintaining a stack of the opening parentheses. When a closing parenthesis is seen, the top of the stack (the last seen opening parenthesis) is popped to verify that it matches the closing parenthesis. If the stack is empty, or the parentheses do not match, we return false. Once all characters have been parsed, a match is indicated by the stack being empty.

```php
function Parenthesis($string) {
    $opening = array('}' => '{', ']' => '[', ')' => '(');
    $parens = array();
    foreach (str_split($string) as $char) {
        switch ($char) {
            case '{':
            case '[':
            case '(':
                $parens[] = $char;
                break;
            case '}':
            case ']':
            case ')':
                if (!count($parens) || array_pop($parens) != $opening[$char]) return false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return count($parens) === 0;
}

function check_balanced($string) {
    echo "$string is " . (Parenthesis($string) ? '' : 'not ') . "balanced\n";
}

check_balanced("{([]){}()}");
check_balanced("{C{}[{[a]}RqhL]{y2}}");
check_balanced("{([]){]()}");
```

Output:

```
{([]){}()} is balanced
{C{}[{[a]}RqhL]{y2}} is balanced
{([]){]()} is not balanced
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/RJftQ)

Comment: Nice one.  Very readable.  You don't need a `break` on `default`, right?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks. You're right, you don't *need* a `break` on `default`, I just like putting one in to keep myself in the habit of always putting a `break` in every branch of a `switch`. It helps me avoid those occasional forgotten ones which cause unexpected side effects...

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are after is long and really hard to maintain. If there must be at least one pair of brackets in the string, this is the pattern you need:

```
\A[^][(){}]*+(?:(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|(\[(?:[^][]++|(?2))*])|({(?:[^{}]++|(?3))*}))[^][(){}]*+)++\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmCvx9/1).

**NOTE**: If the string can have no brackets/braces, you should replace the `++` at the end with `*+` (zero or more occurrences).

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `[^][(){}]*+` - zero or more chars other than `]`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `{` and `}`
- `(?:(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|(\[(?:[^][]++|(?2))*])|({(?:[^{}]++|(?3))*}))[^][(){}]*+)++` - one or more occurrences of

  - `(?:(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|(\[(?:[^][]++|(?2))*])|({(?:[^{}]++|(?3))*}))` - one of the three alternatives:

    - `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))|` - substring between nested `(` and `)` round brackets (parentheses), or
    - `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?2))*])|` - substring between nested `[` and `]` square brackets, or
    - `({(?:[^{}]++|(?3))*})` - substring between nested braces, `{` and `}`
  - `[^][(){}]*+` - zero or more chars other than `]`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `{` and `}`
- `\z` - the very end of string.

Comment: I get: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @NeoTechni That's because you did not use the pattern inside regex delimiters. See [the PHP code snippet here](https://regex101.com/r/EmCvx9/1/codegen?language=php).

Answer (score 0):

```
function isBalanced($s) {
    $compareStack = array('('=>')','['=>']','{'=>'}');
    $individualElement = splitString($s);
    $stack = array();
    foreach($individualElement as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($value, $compareStack)) {
            array_push($stack,$value);
        } else {
            $remove = end($stack);
            if(empty($remove)) {
                return 'NO';
                break;
            }
            if($compareStack[$remove] == $value) {
                array_pop($stack);
            } else {
                return 'NO';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(empty($stack)) {
        return 'YES';    
    } else {
        return 'NO';
    }   
}
```

The input parameter $s is the string. 
e.g.

```
'{([])}' will return YES
'{((])}' will return NO
```